# what does this syntax mean? new { }

Tags: c#

I stumbled upon this weird form of syntax in C#, and was trying to figure out what it means and how to use it. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on the net on this.

```
object data = new { var1 = someValue, var2 = anotherValue }
```

There are no errors with this syntax, so I assume it's something that C# allows. what does it mean?

Comment: Anonymous types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

Comment: Typically you'll use `var data = new { ... };` to preserve the anonymous type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does method ( new { x=y.property } ) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039063/what-does-method-new-x-y-property-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an anonymous type. It will basically work like a class:

```
class anonymous
{
    public readonly type var1; // "type" is the type of somevalue
    public readonly type var2; // "type" is the type of anothervalue
}
```

which is instantiated with

```
var data = new anonymous { var1 = somevalue, var2 = anothervalue };
```

Comment: @TimothyShields Hmm, `readonly` isn't too exact either. They are properties with a getter but no setter, so signature like `public type var1 { get { ... } }`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I know - I was going for closer-to-correct without drastically changing csharpler's answer. Without the `readonly` hint, someone might think that these are mutable fields.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax creates an instance of an "anonymous type".  It is still a statically typed object that is fully type safe, but you can add whatever properties you want at the time you create it.

There is more documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

You can't use an anonymous type as a return type or declare a member field using one.  You can't use one anywhere you have to provide the type name, since it doesn't have one.